# Validation of BOPF object only triggered on save

Tags: abap

I have created a BOPF object as described in the documentation 
[documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc0c305d2fab47bd808adcad3ca7ee9d/1709%20002/en-US/309ceacdb8aa4127b1eace76ee013ec8.html)

According to help the validation will be triggered every time the user presses ENTER or the save button, now I wanted that to happen only if he presses the SAVE button, how can I do that?

Comment: The screenshot in the documentation shows that the validation should have the triggers `Update` and `Delete` active. However, the screenshot is clipped at the right side. Does the validation also have the trigger `Check` active?

Comment: no it doesn't have that flag